# JavaScript equivalent from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

So I have this preg_replace written in PHP, but I have no idea how to rewrite this one in JavaScript. Especially the part for replacment, the search isn't very different I guess.

```
return preg_replace('/ @(\w+)/', ' <a href="' . url("user") . '/${1}">${1}</a>', $text);
```

JavaScript solution:

```
text.replace(/\s@(\w+)/g, "<a href='/user/$1'>$1</a>")
```

Comment: `" @revo".replace(/\s@(\w+)/g, "<a href='/user/$1'>$1</a>")`

Comment: Yeah I found the solution just about minute ago :) Dind't think it's that simple in JS :)

Comment: I wonder what the initial trouble was.

Comment: The only thing you don't get in the javascript version is the url-encoding that the php `url()` function gives you